# "Вопрос на тему" или "вопрос по теме" исследования?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно сказать: вопрос **на тему** исследования или вопрос **по теме** исследования?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подобный вопрос обсуждался: http://forum.lingvo.ru/actualthread.aspx?tid=38769 Последний ответ очень подробный. Его автор считает, что если речь идет об обширной теме и само слово "тема" можно опустить, то употребляется "по теме". Например, вопрос по русскому языку = вопрос по теме "Русский язык".
  Употребление же предлога "на"  требует конкретики. Например, вопрос на тему "Употребление предлогов...".

В Вашем примере словосочетание "тема исследования" воспринимается как  единое целое, поэтому, мне кажется, что допустимы оба варианта.